# Adding a sample Form in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I would like to create a sample Form in Kibana (version 6.3) to add data to elasticsearch. Is there an example or link which I can follow it to create my UI in first step and loading data to elasticsearch in second step?

Thanks for advance ^^

Answer (score 0):

Kibana itself is not meant for data manipulation - it is a discoverability and visualisation tool. You can edit saved search objects, but even Kibana itself discourages it. The following is a copy/paste from the Search Objects interface:

> Typically objects are only modified via their associated application, which is probably what you should use instead of this screen

My suggestion would be to create a simple web app using something like Flask or Padrino, depending on which language you are most comfortable with. For example, [this is how to build a form in Flask](https://pythonspot.com/flask-web-forms/). You can use the [elasticsearch Python module](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py) to record data in the index.

Comment: The idea is to centralize all in the same app (I mean manipulation and analyze data). Thanks for your help ^^

Comment: Perhaps a plugin could be helpful? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/known-plugins.html

Comment: If not, and the idea is that users don't switch between multiple websites, you could host the Form app and Kibana under the same domain using something like https://www.garron.me/en/linux/nginx-reverse-proxy.html

Comment: Thanks for the links ^^ The first one contains a list of plugins I know, but I didn't find any plugin useful to my usecase (Forms). For the second link, my problem isn't have one or two domains. Like I said I would like to centralize all in one instance (Kibana app)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of researchs, I found this two links [1](https://www.timroes.de/2016/02/21/writing-kibana-plugins-custom-applications) & [2](https://github.com/johtani/analyze-api-ui-plugin) (the best documentation I found) to create a plugin with Forms and interaction with Elasticsearch. 
Thanks :)